# Xaml Disable Control untill its code behind is executed

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have made a customized button as shown below

```
<Border x:Name="myBtn" Grid.Column="0" Width="320" Height="100" Margin="10" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Style="{StaticResource myBtnStyle}" Tapped="myBtn_Tapped">
    <Grid>
        <TextBlock x:Uid="TBmyBtn" Margin="100,20,20,20" Text="Update" Style="{StaticResource myTBStyle}"/>
    </Grid>
</Border>
```

Its tapped event is as shown below

```
private async void myBtn_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   //Many Network Calls
   //Updating Local DB
   //Updating ViewModels
   // Blah Blah Blah...
}
```

If i tap my custom button(myBtn) its code behind starts executing, and since there are many network calls, it takes some time to complete myBtn_Tapped function.

Now my requirement is that, i should disable myBtn tap, until myBtn_Tapped completes its execution.

What i had tried is

```
private async void myBtn_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
{
   myBtn.IsTapEnabled=False;
       //Many Network Calls
       //Updating Local DB
       //Updating ViewModels
       // Blah Blah Blah...
   myBtn.IsTapEnabled=True;
}
```

But what i noticed is that even after `myBtn.IsTapEnabled=False;`, if i tap myBtn once, and when myBtn_Tapped function is executing, if i again tap myBtn, the tap event gets registered and the function, after completing its execution, starts executing again.

How do I stop tap event registration for myBtn untill its code behind is in transaction??

Comment: How about you try myBtn.IsEnabled = false?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I handled this situation.
I declared a flag in this particular page class & set its value to `true` when method starts & when my work is done, set it to `false`.

```
public class myControl : UserControl
{
    public bool IsWorking { get; set; }

    private async void myBtn_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
       if (IsWorking)   //These 2 statements did the magic.!!
            return;

       IsWorking= true;

       //Many Network Calls
       //Updating Local DB
       //Updating ViewModels
       // Blah Blah Blah...

       IsWorking= false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what "disabled" really means, but `IsHitTestVisible` is likely going to give you the best bang for your buck here.

```
async ClickHandler(sender, events)
{
    Control.IsHitTestVisible = false;
    await GetDataAsync();
    Control.IsHitTestVisible = true;
}
```

// Best of luck!

Comment: Thnx Sir for your answer. But I didn't implement it this way. Just check my answer and correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Don't implement your application logic in code-behind. That's violating the MVVM idea. You should implement your

> //Many Network Calls
>
> //Updating Local DB
>
> //Updating ViewModels
>
> // Blah Blah Blah...

in the view model, e.g. providing an `ICommand` which you bind to the button's `Command` property. That `ICommand` should also implement the `CanExecute()` method that will set your button to enabled or disabled state.
Then you could define a `Style` for your button so it looks as you wish.

So in the end you end up with your view like this:

```
<Button Command="{Binding UpdateCommand}"/>
```